# Xampp Internet Connection

Tags: php, xampp, connection

I was wondering if someone could please help me with an internet connection issue I'm having?

I have Xampp installed and I'm trying to follow a web scraping tutorial, but I can't connect Xammp to the internet so I don't know if I'm following the tutorial correctly or not.
I've looked all over the place for instructions but the only ones I can find are about how to make Xammp accessible from the internet (being able to use Xampp remotely), not the other way around.
I've looked on Youtube and the Apache forums but can't find answers there either.

I've double-checked that I don't have internet access from Xampp by opening an html page with an iframe on localhost with google as the source, but I get the Chrome 'sad face/no connection' icon.
I've tried changing the 'listen' port name in the httpd.conf file to 8080 as some people have suggested, and tried listening to my IP address, and combinations of the two but nothing seems to work.
It seems like it must be an easy fix but I don't know what to do.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!
Thank you for your time:)

Comment: maybe try to check your firewall. It maybe blocking xampp.

Comment: Thank you for that, I forgot to mention that I looked in my firewall but Xampp has been allowed.
Thanks though:)